How to remove duplicates if a specific value exists
My SparkSQL DataFrame looks like this:
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
|a          |b         |c         |d         |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
|        123|       abc|         N|         2|
|        123|       abc|         N|         4|
|        123|       abc|         X|         3|
|        456|       def|         K|         1|
|        456|       def|         X|         4|
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+

I want to remove duplicates based on the key columns a and b that don't have value N in column c IF there exists a single row for that key combination that has value N in column c.
Expected output:
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
|a          |b         |c         |d         |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+
|        123|       abc|         N|         2|
|        123|       abc|         N|         4|
|        456|       def|         K|         1|
|        456|       def|         X|         4|
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+

For key combination a = 123, b = abc there exists more than one row where c = N. Therefore we want to remove all rows for that key combination where c != N.
For key combination a = 456, b = def there doesn't exist any rows where c = N. Therefore we do not want to remove any rows.

You can get required result by following below steps:

Pyspark

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = # Read data
# Get a, b group where N is present
df_N = df.filter(col('c') == 'N').groupBy('a', 'b').agg(count('c').alias('count_N'))

# Join with original dataframe and apply required filter
df_out = df.join(df_N, on=['a', 'b'], how='left') \
             .filter((col('count_N').isNull()) | (col('c') == 'N')) \
             .drop('count_N')

df_out.show()

+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|123|abc|  N|  2|
|123|abc|  N|  4|
|456|def|  K|  1|
|456|def|  X|  4|
+---+---+---+---+


Spark-SQL

spark.sql("""
    SELECT *
    FROM <table_name>
    WHERE (a, b) NOT IN (
        SELECT a, b
        FROM<table_name>
        WHERE c = 'N'
        GROUP BY a, b
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
    )
    OR c = 'N'
""")

